# Parse message_body(XML) 

Tags: sql-server, xml

I know the contents of @message_body are:

```
<inserted DocNo="xxxx99999"/>
```

I want to put 'DocNo' into a variable I created `@DocNo` and have tried various this such as:

```
SET @DocNo = (SELECT ref.value('@DocNo', 'nvarchar(255)')
              FROM @message_body.nodes('//Sample_Message') T(ref))
```

with no luck. I don't have much experience parsing XML with SQL. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no XML element `Sample_Message`. Shouldn't you be querying for `@message_body.nodes('//inserted')` instead?

Comment: Yeah probably, I'm not very experience with parsing XML using MSSQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @docNo nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @message_body xml = N'<inserted DocNo="12345"/>'

SELECT
    @docNo = @message_body.value('/inserted[1]/@DocNo', 'nvarchar(255)')

SELECT @docNo
```